# A dictionary with values that are dictionaries: trying to sum across those keys in python

Tags: python, hash, dictionary

Data structure is a dictionary, each value is another dictionary, like:

```
>>> from lib import schedule
>>> schedule = schedule.Schedule()
>>> game = schedule.games[0]
>>> game.home
<lib.schedule.Team instance at 0x9d97c6c>
>>> game.home.lineup
{'guerv001': {'HR': 392, '1B': 1297}, 'kendh001': {'HR': 12, '1B': 201}, 'andeg001': {'HR': 272, '1B': 1572}, 'mattg002': {'HR': 104, '1B': 632}, 'figgc001': {'HR': 26, '1B': 672}, 'iztum001': {'HR': 16, '1B': 253}, 'huntt001': {'HR': 213, '1B': 834}, 'quinr002': {'HR': 23, '1B': 200}, 'napom001': {'HR': 46, '1B': 96}}
```

Would like Team to have a method getTotals(self, category) where if you called:

```
game.home.getTotals('HR')
```

The method would, in this case, yield:

```
1104
```

Essentially you can see what I'm trying to do. Any ideas?

**update:** I have this working with two list comprehensions but would like to winnow it down to one:

```
def getTotals(self, category):
    cats = [x for x in self.lineup.values()]
    return sum([x[category] for x in cats])
```

**another update:** Based on [inspectorg4dget](https://stackoverflow.com/users/198633/inspectorg4dget)'s helpful feedback below I've gotten it. Thanks!

```
def getTotals(self, category):
    return sum(self.lineup[man][category] for man in self.lineup.keys())
```

**final update:** Based on [Nadia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97828/nadia-alramli)'s feedback, here's another approach:

```
def getTotals(self, category):
    return sum(value.get(category, 0) for value in self.lineup.values())
```

Comment: Would you consider adding a 'dictionary' tag to this question so that it is easy to find in the future?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a generator expression:

```
def total(category):
    return sum(value.get(category, 0) for value in game.home.lineup.values())

>>> total('HR')
1104
```

I used [dict.get](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to make the default 0 if the category is missing from any dictionary.

The self version:

```
def total(self, category):
    return sum(value.get(category, 0) for value in self.lineup.values())
```

Comment: I changed that to make it a class member of Team but it throws a 'Too many values to unpack' exception when implemented like so:

return sum(value.get(category, 0) for key, value in self.lineup)

Comment: Please try again now. I fixed it.

Comment: Sorry for being pedantic, I think you mean you're using a generator expression, not a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

```
def total(category):
    return sum([ghl[man][category] for man in game.home.lineup.keys()])
```

Comment: return sum(man[category] for man in self.lineup.keys())
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Sorry about the bad code. It has been changed now and tested against your test case. It works. The problem was with misplaced '[]'s, which was a typo. It's test time before the finals, which is why the quality of my code isn't at it's best. Sorry again

Answer (score 0):

```
def myGetTotals(self, team):
    count = 0
    for aKey in self.lineup:
        if team in self.lineup[aKey]:
            count = count + self.lineup[aKey][team]
    return count
```

Kind of verbose, but meh. Do pay attention to the first parameter which is the instance. Now, if you want it to be part of all team objects, you'd need to modify the class:

```
lib.schedule.Team.getTotals = myGetTotals
```

That should add said object to the class definition and make existing objects capable of using it from there on forth. It's been a few months since I coded some Python, but it should work.

Comment: Weird code. Wouldn't `team in self.lineup` be a constant over the entire function? If so, it's the same as this: `return sum(self.lineup[aKey][team] for aKey in self.lineup) if team in self.lineup else 0` or even `return sum(something[team] for something in self.lineup.values()) if team in self.lineup else 0`

Comment: Yeah, I made a booboo in my rush, which is fixed now (thanks!). `if team in self.lineup[aKey]:` is the proper line. Either way, other people had already posted the proper answers by the time I posted, so my focus was primarily on having something to use with the second block of code which had not been addressed yet.